# Почему добавляется только последний элемент в List

Tags: java, list

Нужно добавить в лист 5 элементов, но добавляется 5 последних(item5)
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
    private static List <Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void itemList() {
        Item item1 = new Item("item1", 100);
        Item item2 = new Item("item2", 200);
        Item item3 = new Item("item3", 300);
        Item item4 = new Item("item4", 400);
        Item item5 = new Item("item5", 500);

        itemsList.add(item1);
        itemsList.add(item2);
        itemsList.add(item3);
        itemsList.add(item4);
        itemsList.add(item5);
    }

    public void getItemsList() {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(itemsList.get(i));
            }
    }

    public static List<Item> setItemsList() {
        return itemsList;
    }
}
```

Тут я добавляю метод, отвечающий за вывод объектов из листа и добавление в новый лист выбранный объект

```
public class StoreBasket{
private InsertItems ii = new InsertItems();
    private static List<Item> employeeItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public void addEmployeeItems(){
        ii.getItemsList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        employeeItems.add(ii.setItemsList().get(number-1));
    }
}
```

Тут вызываю метод itemList, отвечающий за добавление в лист объектов

```
public void ShowTheMenu() {
case 2:
                        ii.itemList();
                        storeBasket.addEmployeeItems();
                        break;
    }
```

Comment: хоть вы и показываете какие то непонятные обрывки кода, которые не помогают, мне кажется, вы путаете понятия "класс" и "экземпляр класса"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно в классе Item у тебя есть `static` переменные и/или методы, например

`private static String name;`

Тебе нужно поменять подобные переменные на не `static`, то есть поменять на

`private String name;`